# Objective-C JSON - Convert JSON object to native object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

```
{"status": "FRE", "list": [{"make": "Toyota", "id": 1, "model": "camry", "engine": "Four Cylinder"}{"make": "Ford", "id": 3, "model": "focus", "engine": "Four Cylinder"}]}
```

How do I extract each "`car`" `JSON object` and put it into a native `object`?  I'm using [SBJSON](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/api/3.0/).  Here is my current code, but it is only able to extract one car element, when I need to be able to iterate through each car object and save it:

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
     NSString *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];

     NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"id",@"make",@"model",@"engine", nil];
     NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[responseDict valueForKeyPath:@"list.make"],[responseDict valueForKeyPath:@"list.model"],[responseDict valueForKeyPath:@"list.id"],[responseDict valueForKeyPath:@"list.engine"] , nil];

     self.car = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reason like this.. 
when you do `[[[request responseString] JSONValue] valueForKey:@"list"]];` it will return an array of list of your `cars`.

Then you iterate each `array` and save it into your `car` element...

Example:

```
NSArray *arrayCar =  [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[[request responseString] JSONValue] valueForKey:@"list"]];


for (NSDictionary *carDict in arrayCar) {
Car car = [[Car alloc] init]; 
car.id = [carDict valueForKey:@"id"]; 
car.origin= [carDict valueForKey:@"make"];
 ... ... }
```

Comment: Works great. I just wasn't quite getting it, but understand now completely.

Comment: Any special resaon for using arrayWithArray: even when list should be an array? Does it check type?

Comment: No it does not check type, I gave an example of an array referring to the example given above.. If not, i normally do a class check : `if ([[[request responseString] JSONValue] valueForKey] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]) `.. `else if ([[[request responseString] JSONValue]  valueForKey:@"list"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] `...

Comment: You need to know what kind of format you will receive and you will treat in the client's side.. and treat all the case possible, for example if i'm getting [[[request responseString] JSONValue] valueForKey:@"FRE"], it will return an NSDictionary instead of NSArray

Answer (score 9):

Instead of doing everything manually, use Jastor - https://github.com/elado/jastor
You just need to create simple classes and `initWithDictionary` will do the entire assigning work for you.