# regex to detect a pattern in a JSON string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex

I have a string like this

```
"Settings" : { "UserId" : 3, "UserToken" : "4578965235874158", "SecurityCode" : "111", "Password" : "12345", "UserPhone" : "555-555-1531", "drop" : -1, "UserLastName" : "Smith" }
```

I need a regular expression pattern to find the value of the `"UserToken"`( in this example `4578965235874158`)

Sorry if this is a "Give me code" question, but I never worked with regular expressions and I do not have much time to learn and try to do it myself.

Thanks for help.

**Additional notes:**
I will use it in objective-C for an iPhone application. I don't know if that affect anything but just in case.

**EDIT**'
The pattern is: the key is always `"UserToken"` followed by a space then by a `:` then another space after that comes the value inside double Quotes `"`. I would like to get this value.

Comment: Describe a pattern for the token. For example, "exactly n digits" etc.

Comment: does it need to be regex? JSON values can be accessed by their key. You just need an [objective-c json parser](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc)

Comment: Has the json always the same format?
In that case I'd rather use a JSON parser than regex magic.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov I edit my question with the pattern.

Comment: @Viehzeug I need to use regex because I dont know where the "settings" key is located inside the Json. It might be at the root level or inside another key. and I am trying to avoid looping on all the key and inner keys

Comment: May be you need to have a look on how to convert the json to an Object than you can access the object attribute without REGEX, please [see this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589794/objective-c-json-convert-json-object-to-native-object)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a json format you don't really need to parse it with regex, but if you need to, this can be a solution:

```
(?<="UserToken"\s:\s")\d+
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have converted it and access all information I need like:

```
NSString *str = @"\"Settings\" : { \"UserId\" : 3, \"UserToken\" : \"4578965235874158\", \"SecurityCode\" : \"111\", \"Password\" : \"12345\", \"UserPhone\" : \"555-555-1531\", \"drop\" : -1, \"UserLastName\" : \"Smith\" }";

//NSDictionary *jsonDict = [str JSONValue];

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
```

than all information are stored on the results NSDictionary, just have to do something like: `[results valueForKey:(NSString *)]` or `[results objectForKey::(NSString *)]`

Comment: Thanks for this but I need to use Regex

Comment: Welcome :) around here, we say thanks by upvotes :) perhaps if I I'll try to look & write you later a method using Regex (I don't have it on minde right now)