# JSONModel: json to array?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, jsonmodel

Is it possible to parse json to an array of JSONModel objects using JSONModel? Like parse json below:

```
[{"id" : 1}, {"id" : 2}]
```

to two JSONModel objects having property of "id".

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589794/objective-c-json-convert-json-object-to-native-object  and https://github.com/elado/jastor

Comment: I'm using JSONModel all of my project

Comment: @keywind Please accept an answer for this question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries: on your model class like so:

```
NSArray* models = [YourModelClass arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries: objects];
```

This will go over "objects" and convert each dictionary to a model and you get the result in models. If any item in objects fail to convert to model "models" will be nil.

Here's the class docs for this method:
[http://jsonmodel.com/docs/Classes/JSONModel.html#//api/name/arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:](http://jsonmodel.com/docs/Classes/JSONModel.html#//api/name/arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries%3a)

Comment: This method would still work if I am using a JSON object that returns information related to a specific location correct? I know alot of the tutorials have it returning an array for say XX amount of results. My JSON object is tide data based on a single location with parts I want to extract out.

Answer (score 1):

Why not trying [BWJSONMatcher](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher)?

First you should declare your own data model:

```
@interface MyDataModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger id;
@end
```

Then you can easily get your array with [BWJSONMatcher](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher) within one line:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [BWJSONMatcher matchJSON:jsonString withClass:[MyDataModel class]];
```

Hope this could help you.